# Android: Grid view with clickable grid items and nested views (buttons, checkboxes)

Tags: android, gridview

Basically, I would like to implement a `GridView` wherein the items themselves are clickable, but within the `GridView` are clickable `Button`s and `Checkbox`es.

Here's a sample layout:

```
Gridview
-----------------------------------------
|[ImageView]        |[ImageView]        |
|[TextView]         |[TextView]         |
|[Button][Checkbox] |[Button][Checkbox] |
-----------------------------------------
|[ImageView]        |[ImageView]        |
|[TextView]         |[TextView]         |
|[Button][Checkbox] |[Button][Checkbox] |
-----------------------------------------
```

Basically, what i want to do is, when the user clicks the `CheckBox`, multiple items can now be selected from the `GridView`. When the users clicks the `Button`, A `Popup` is shown. When the user clicks anywhere else, a new `Activity` is started. The whole point of this is instead of long-pressing to show the context menu, I would like a button to take its place.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this scenario? In my current setup, if I add the `Button` within the adapter's `GetView()` method, only the `Button` is clickable. The whole `GridView` item is not clickable. When I remove the `Button`, the `GridView` item is clickable again. It seems that it's only the whole `GridView` Item or the `Button` is clickable (responds to `OnClickListener()`. Is there a way to make them both clickable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This post is old, but just for reference/googlers, I have the following solution:

You need to write all the events for buttons, checkboxes in getView of the imageAdapter only.
Then in your layout.xml file under the gridview tag add these lines:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

and add these lines to your button and checkboxes:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

And if you want some other activity to start if any other area of the gridview item is clicked/touched you would need to use the (standard code)/(your own matching implementation):

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Cheers,
        });

Answer (score 1):

You can make an *item* xml and use it as your gridView item. Then with an adapter initialize the buttons and checkboxes in your gridView. After you can add your clickListener not to the gridView items, but to the layout in the *item* xml, so it's child views won't respond to the click event.

Comment: Yes, i currently have that set-up. My problem is with the `OnClickListeners()`. When I add the `Button`, the `OnClickListener()` of the entire `GridView` item is not fired, only the `Button`'s `OnClickListener()`. I'm looking for a way to have both the whole `GridView`'s and the `Button`'s `OnClickListener()`s fire-able, if there's such a term.

Comment: You could try added OnClickListener() not to the entire GridView but to the layout containing it. So when user click on anywhere in the gridView but your buttons this event will be fired

Comment: I think you did not get what I meant, but I get your idea. It's not the whole `GridView` but the specific `GridViewItem` that I want to be clickable. I'll try implementing `OnClickListener()`s to both the `ImageView` and `TextVied`, or encase them both in a `LinearLayout` and implement an `OnClickListener()` on that `LinearLayout`.