# Android how to call onitemclicklisner from custom view onclicklisner?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am customized an adapter for listview and its word fine. But when i set onclicklistener to an view in custom adapter row view the onitemclicklistner not working.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    try{
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_row_view, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.Name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ProeprtyName);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RightArrow);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

      holder.Name.setText(propertyNames[position]);
      if(selectedPosition == position){
          Log.d("", "selected");
          convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
          convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3B79FF"));
          holder.Name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      }else{
          //convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.savsearch_bg_district);
          holder.Name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      }
      holder.Name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("fdsf", "on");
                Globalclass global = (Globalclass) ((Activity)context).getApplication();
                global.setMarkerTextClick(true);
            }
      });
      holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("fdsf", "on");
                Globalclass global = (Globalclass) ((Activity)context).getApplication();
                global.setMarkerTextClick(false);
            }
      });

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

and the code for listview onitemclicklisner is

```
final MarkerInfoAdapter adapter = new MarkerInfoAdapter(PropertyMapList.this, names);
                                final ListView list = (ListView) CustomMarker.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                                list.setAdapter(adapter);list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(
                                            AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                                        Log.d("", "fsdfdsfds");
                                        ((MarkerInfoAdapter)adapter).setSelected(arg2);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: try CustomMarker.list.setOnItemClickListener......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113969/onclicklistner-not-working-in-fragment-listview

Comment: Which are the views you trying to implement `onClicklistener()` ??

Comment: I want to know which view is clicked (Text or Image), If text means i will call some function and Image means will call other one.. i can get the view click so i implemented this onclicklisner for each view now this working but cant get the onitemclickLisner for listview??

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               setSelected(position); 
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the same code in in onClick listener ,there no point of using on click listener on row views.Instead you can add the following code in onItemClick

```
 Globalclass global = (Globalclass) ((Activity)context).getApplication();
   global.setMarkerTextClick(false);
```

If you still want to implement on click on specific views ,make sure

- views are not clickable
- android:focusable="false"
- android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Add the following attributes in your listview tag

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

This link will solve your problem [Android: Grid view with clickable grid items and nested views (buttons, checkboxes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386340/android-grid-view-with-clickable-grid-items-and-nested-views-buttons-checkbox/12812070#12812070)

Comment: Onclick of **textview** i want that itemclicklistener to function and onclick of the **rightArrow(image)** i need to do some logical work for marker class...